# Magento2: Block Controller Issue

Tags: magento2, controllers, custom-block

When I call to controller first time showing my data on page after some seconds data not showing on page. page is showing blank.

**Controller**

```
public function execute()
{
    $itemid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('itemid');
    $this->_coreRegistry->register('itemid', $itemid);
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    return $resultPage;
    //$this->_redirect('csr/index/find');
}
```

After some time $itemid not getting me.

Comment: You mean after some times page load automatically, and after reload page will become blank.

Comment: No, Some time page not reload but I taking product data from block. Product id have taken blank after some time. @Ravi

Comment: I think second time block not found. @Ravi

Comment: I have debugged getting $tempBlock = null  @Ravi

Comment: You should add your custom code here so everyone can understand.

Comment: I have added controller @Ravi